# Estimating the following ratio: $\frac{\sup_{A \succeq 0 : \, \mathrm{tr}(A) \leq 1} f(A)}{\sup_{a :\, \|a\|_2 \leq 1} f(aa^T)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-semidefinite

Let $B$ be a positive semidefinite matrix and let $x$ be a fixed nonzero vector.

For any positive semidefinite matrix $A$, define
$$
f(A) = x^TA(A + ABA)^\dagger A x 
$$
Above $P^\dagger$ denotes the Moore Penrose pseudoinverse of $P$.

I want to calculate (or estimate) the ratio
$$
R(x, B) := \frac{\sup_{A \succeq 0 :\, \mathrm{tr}(A) \leq 1} f(A)}{\sup_{a :\, \left\|a\right\|_2 \leq 1} f(aa^T)}
$$
Evidently, the ratio is at least $1$, since $aa^T$ has trace at most $1$ when $\left\|a\right\|_2 \leq 1$.

There is one case where we can see this holds:

- For the special case $B = I$, this is easily checked directly, and we can see that the ratio is equal to 1. Indeed, in this case, we have with eigendecomposition $A = \sum_{j=1}^d \lambda_j u_j u_j^T$,
  $$
  f(A) = x^TA(A + A^2)^\dagger A x = \sum_{j=1}^d (x^T u_j)^2 \frac{\lambda_j}{1 + \lambda_j} \leq \|x\|_2^2/2. 
  $$
  since $\lambda/(1+\lambda) \leq 1/2$ for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. Moreover, this upper bound is attained at $A = xx^T/\|x\|_2^2$. Since this is a symmetric, rank-one matrix,  we see that the ratio is indeed equal to $1$ for $B = I$.

I am not sure how to generalize this argument to non-identity $B$.

Comment: Stupid remark: the ratio is not $+\infty$ if and only if the numerator is not $+\infty$

Comment: I guess I should add that I also would like to estimate this ratio, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us prove that
$$\sup_{A \succeq 0 :\, \mathrm{tr}(A) \leq 1} f(A) = \sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T). \tag{1}$$

First, clearly we have
$$\sup_{A \succeq 0 :\, \mathrm{tr}(A) \leq 1} f(A) \ge \sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T). \tag{2}$$

Second, let us prove that if $\mathrm{rank}(A) \ge 2$,
then
$$f(A) \le \sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T). \tag{3}$$

1. We have
   $$f(A) = x^T (I + AB)^{-1}A x. \tag{4}$$
   (The proof is easy.)
2. Let us prove that
   $$(I + B)^{-1} \succeq (I + AB)^{-1} A. \tag{5}$$

We use continuity argument. For $t > 0$, we have
$$(I + (A + tI)B)^{-1} (A + tI)
= ((A + tI)^{-1} + B)^{-1}.$$

Since $\mathrm{rank}(A) \ge 2$, there exist $t_0 > 0$ such that
$I - (A + tI)$ is PD for all $0 < t < t_0$.
Thus, $(I + tA)^{-1} - I$ is PD for all $0 < t < t_0$.
Thus, $(I + B)^{-1} \succeq ((A + tI)^{-1} + B)^{-1}$ for all $0 < t < t_0$.
Thus, $(I + B)^{-1} \succeq (I + (A + tI)B)^{-1} (A + tI)$ for all $0 < t < t_0$.
Taking $t\to 0$, we have $(I + B)^{-1} \succeq (I + AB)^{-1} A$.

From (4) and (5), we have
$$f(A) \le x^T(I + B)^{-1} x. \tag{6}$$

3. Using (4), we have
   $$f(aa^T) = x^T (I + aa^TB)^{-1}aa^T x = \frac{(x^Ta)^2}{1 + a^TBa}.$$

We have
$$\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{1+a^TBa} = \sup_{a\ne 0, ~\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{a^Ta+a^TBa}. \tag{7}$$
(*Proof*: First, we have $\mathrm{LHS} \le \mathrm{RHS}$
since $\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{1+a^TBa} \le \frac{(x^Ta)^2}{a^Ta+a^TBa}$.
Second, note that $\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{a^Ta+a^TBa}$ is homogeneous. Thus, we can find $b$ with $b^Tb = 1$
such that $\sup_{a\ne 0, ~\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{a^Ta+a^TBa} = \frac{(x^Tb)^2}{b^Tb+b^TBb} = \frac{(x^Tb)^2}{1+b^TBb}  \le \mathrm{LHS}$. We are done.)

Thus, we have
$$\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T) = \sup_{a\ne 0, ~\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{a^Ta+a^TBa} =  x^T(I + B)^{-1}x. \tag{8}$$

4. From (6) and (8), we have (3).

From (2) and (3), we have (1).

We are done.

Comment: There is a simpler proof of your inequality $(I + B)^{-1} \succeq A(A + ABA)^+ A$. Write $A (A + ABA)^+ A = A^{1/2} (I + A^{1/2} B A^{1/2})^{-1} A^{1/2}$. Then note that to verify your inequality w.l.o.g $A$ is invertible. It then writes $I + A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} \succeq A + A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$. So we need $A \preceq I$, which is implied by $\mathrm{tr}(A) \leq 1, A \succeq 0$.

Comment: Also regarding the claim that $\sup_{\|a\|_2 \leq 1} f(aa^T) = x^T(I + B)^{-1} x$, the proof can be shortened somewhat: first note that for any $a$, $f(\delta^2 aa^T) \geq f(aa^T)$ for any $\delta > 1$. Therefore, we may restrict the supremum to $\|a\|=. 1$. Then the equality follows by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @DrewBrady Both are nice.

Answer (score 2):

For any Hermitian matrix $S$, denote by $\Pi_S$ the orthogonal projection matrix onto $\operatorname{range}(S)$. Note that $A(A+ABA)^+A=A^{1/2}\left(I+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}$ because
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(I+AB)A(A+ABA)^+A\\
&=(A+ABA)(A+ABA)^+A\\
&=\Pi_{A+ABA}A\\
&=A\\
&=A^{1/2}\left(I+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)\left(I+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}\\
&=(I+AB)A^{1/2}\left(I+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(A)
&=x^TA^{1/2}\left(I+A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}x\\
&\le x^TA^{1/2}\left(I+\lambda_\min(B)A\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}x\\
&\le \left\|A^{1/2}\left(I+\lambda_\min(B)A\right)^{-1}A^{1/2}\right\|_2\|x\|_2^2\\
&=\frac{\lambda_\max(A)\|x\|_2^2}{1+\lambda_\min(B)\lambda_\max(A)}\\
&\le\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{1+\lambda_\min(B)},\\
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last inequality is due to the fact that $\lambda_\max(A)\le\operatorname{tr}(A)\le1$.
Similarly, we also have
$$
\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T)
=\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{1+a^TBa}
\ge\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}\frac{(x^Ta)^2}{1+\lambda_\max(B)\|a\|_2^2}
=\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{1+\lambda_\max(B)}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\sup_{A\succeq0,\,\operatorname{tr}(A)\le1}f(A)}{\sup_{\|a\|_2\le1}f(aa^T)}
\le\frac{1+\lambda_\max(B)}{1+\lambda_\min(B)}.
$$
I have a feeling that the ratio in question is equal to $1$, but am not able to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not complete and prove only that $f$ is concave.

Let assume that, $B\succ 0$ and let $D = B^{-1}$ then it is easy to prove that:

$$f(A) = x^\intercal \left(A - A\left(D + A\right)^{-1}A\right)x$$

Indeed if $A$ is invertible, then by [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Woodbury_matrix_identity),

$$A\left(A + ABA\right)^{+}A = A\left(A + ABA\right)^{-1}A = A - A\left(D+A\right)^{-1}A$$

and if $A\succeq 0$ apply it for $A + \varepsilon I$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Now fix $X, Y \succeq 0$ and let $Z(t) = (1-t)X+tY$,

$$\varphi(t) = f(Z(t))$$

It is not hard to prove that:

\begin{align}
\varphi''(t) &= -2 x^\intercal\left(Z' (D+Z)^{-1}Z' -2Z(D+Z)^{-1}Z'(D+Z)^{-1} + Z(D+Z)^{-1}Z'(D+Z)^{-1}Z'(D+Z)^{-1}Z\right)x\\
&= -2\left\|(D+Z)^{-\frac12}\left(Z' - (D+Z)^{-1} Z\right)x\right\|^2 \le 0
\end{align}

This proves that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Yes it can. Just add small $\varepsilon$

Comment: Oh I realized there is a logical error: convex functions are maximized on compact convex sets at extreme points. But, as you indicate, the function is concave, not convex.

Comment: That's correct. I will however let the answer may be the concavity is something useful!